# Retrofit request

Tags: java, retrofit, request

Подскажите пожалуйста где в Retofit можно посмотреть url запроса, с ключами, обязательными параметрами и т.п. в полном виде? И приходящий от сервера ответ, до  его обработки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

1. Создать `LoggingInterceptor`, в котором указать что показывать. Например адрес, заголовки, тело ответа (BODY):

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Log.d("Retrofit", message)).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
```

2. Задать его для `OkHttpClient`

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor ).build();
```

3. Задать полученный клиент для ретрофита при создании оного:

```
new Retrofit.Builder().client(client);
```

---

Для этого всего надо подключить либу

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
```

А для использования лямбд надо или использовать 8 яяву или подключить либу `Retrolambda`

Comment: Спасибо. Логи читаю. Я бы в ответ добавил, что необходимо подключить библиотеку compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1' и так же подключить поддержку Java 8 для использования лямбда. https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=ru